# VS Code editor - 2 columns layout issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've updated my VS Code up to June 2018 (version 1.25) and noticed that its editor has lost some functionality. Before If I had 2 editors opened I can click on not active editor's area or use Ctrl + 1 or Ctrl + 2 keys and it expanded it fully my screen but now it does nothing, the editor area stays closed(narrow). And now I have to expand the area by using mouse drag&drop action.

How do I get this functionality back? I tried to search it within the Settings but no lucky.

Comment: Thanks God! Finally they've fixed it in version 1.26.1....ummmmm